# Toggle two divs query

Tags: javascript, jquery, toggle, hide, show

Hi i would like to toggle two divs. I made it basic way but i really want to write it this way and i have no idea what is wrong with this. Could someone help me with it ?

```
    (function($) {

    var showAll = function() {
        this.$button = this.find('.btn-all-events');
        this.$all = this.find('.all-events');
        this.$recent = this.find('.recent-events');

        this.initEvents();
    };

    showAll.prototype = {
        initEvents: function() {

            if (this.$all) {
                this.$button.on('click', this.showEvents.bind(this));
            }
        },

        showEvents: function() {
            this.$recent.hide();
            this.$all.show();
        }
    };

    this.toggle = new showAll($(this));
})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `$(this).find()` not `this.find()` Like below

```
$(this).find('.btn-all-events');
```

Comment: I replace this in var and still doesn't works for me

Answer (score 0):

Toggle div simply using jquery . You can check here https://jsfiddle.net/surendra786/os09Lhfw/

```
html --   
   <div class="main">
    <div class="first">Divdfasdfasdfsd</div>
    <div class="second hide">afsdfasfasdfasdfsdf</div>
   </div>
  <a class="toggle">toggle</a>

css--

<style>
 .hide {
display:none;
 }
</style>

 js---

 $('.toggle').click(function(){
if($('.first').hasClass('hide')){
$('.first').removeClass('hide');
} else {
$('.first').addClass('hide');
}
if($('.second').hasClass('hide')){
$('.second').removeClass('hide');
 } else {
$('.second').addClass('hide');
 }
});
```

try this it should work, please up if working